# Using WIA Scanner is not running in asp.net iis server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am getting this error:

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
>   {850D1D11-70F3-4BE5-9A11-77AA6B2BB201} from the IClassFactory failed
>   due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: Why do you want to run it on the server?